# Is there a way to achieve multiple headers based on row in a gridview in asp.net? If not what control can I use as an alternative?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-controls

[I need the form to look like this.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUcYc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A gridview, or listview, or even a repeater?

that is for a TABLE of data, and repeating data that you want to display.

In your example, you have ONE record to display. So, I suppose you could use a formview, but unless there is repeating data here?

Then just build the markup. Your example "might" look like a grid or table layout, but it is NOT really a table of data rows, but is ONE row. This is a VAST different issue then, right?

You don't really have a bunch of rows here, but have a form like layout in which values are to be entered.

Unless there is additional details here, I don't see a table of a data, but I MOST certainly see a ROW of data.

However it is possible that your design will put the questions part into a database. So, thus, the question then becomes do you need the ability to add more questions to the survey over time, or do you expect this system to be "rather static" for the information to be entered into that form?

What REALLY drives how this will work? The database structure will often rather force your hand. So, what kind of data base schema are you using to store this ONE reocrd result? Or is the survey going to have multiple rows?

So, what control and how you do this?

VERY much will be defined on how your database tables (schema) will look. So, design the database structure first, as that will THEN much force your hand as to what controls you use on the web page, and how you plan to layout the page.

I think just dropping floated divs probably going to be the most easy, and in fact may well be a better choice then attempting to use HTML tables.

Comment: Yes this is a form, and the questions are subjected to change more than often. This is why I did not want to use a static form for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nested gridview.

Here's the reference : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b926a6/nested-grid-view-in-Asp-Net/